# Syntax issue when updating records with info from combo box

Tags: sql, ms-access

Essentially I would like to update a subforms column values with a name found in a combo box.

A table called **"tbl_jobs"** is the source behind the subform, the column I am trying to update is called **"Person_Name"**.

The combo box is called **"PersonCombo"** .

I am working on creating a query called **"updateRecord"** using the Access query designer that is executed by the button **"updateButton"**

**The following is how the query will be executed:**

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "updateRecord"
```

**The content of the query is what I am having trouble with:**

```
UPDATE tbl_jobs SET Person_Name = '" & PersonCombo & "' WHERE [Select] = True
```

Instead of filling the column data with the values from the chosen name in "PersonCombo" like Jamie, Mickey, Haley, etc. (values from PersonCombo) it just says ***" & PersonCombo & "***

**What is wrong with my syntax?**

Comment: Note: `Select` is a terrible name for a column, since it's a reserved word in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a saved query, it doesn't know about the current form.

You need to use the full path to the control, but no concatenation, e.g.

```
UPDATE tbl_jobs SET Person_Name = Forms!myForm!PersonCombo WHERE [Select] = True
```

If the combo box is on a subform, refer to:
[Forms: Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)

e.g. `Forms!Mainform!Subform1.Form!ControlName`

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can pass a variable to a saved query. Instead build the query in code and run it:

```
dim SQL as string
PersonCombo = "thePerson"
SQL = "UPDATE tbl_jobs SET Person_Name = '" & PersonCombo & "' WHERE [Select] = True"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```